# Unable to access HTML files from spring MVC

Tags: html, spring, annotations

I am writing basic spring mvc application which have no xml configuration its annotation based. I am trying to access html files like
" localhost:9090/help.html " but i get error
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/help.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

here is my config

```
@EnableWebMvc  
@Configuration  
@ComponentScan({ "com.example.test" })  
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/jsp/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return internalResourceViewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry){
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/*");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**/*").addResourceLocations("/templates/*");
    }
}
```

my html pages are inside
webapp->templates

i have tried many question here but none helped and all of them relates to xml config

any suggestions ??

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured this out. It was just a silly mistake. In `addResourceLocations` i removed `*` at the end and bingo issued resolved

so this is wrong

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/*");
```

correct form is

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources");
```

Now i can access html pages directly like

```
localhost:8080/resources/help.html
```

even this is possible now

```
localhost:8080/help.html
```

because i have added another resource-handler as `addResourceHandler("/*\*/**")`